# Calculate duration column from two 24:00:00 time columns

Tags: r, date, time

I have two columns, one is start_time and the other is end_time. The time is formmated in 24:00:00 time. I have situations when the start_time was at 23:00:00 and the end_time was at 02:00:00. How do I go about accounting for the duration from late nights to early mornings? Do I need to go down the route of case_when?

| start_time | end_time | duration | start_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16:34:23 | 19:24:45 |  | 2019-04-02 |
| 23:12:34 | 04:12:34 |  | 2019-07-03 |

```
df_dur <- df %>% 
  mutate(duration = (end_time - start_time))
```

Comment: Are there criteria for what date each start_time and end_time are? In the first row, there is nothing stopping the difference from being 27 hours instead of 3, as the second row sets the precedent of the date being misleading.

Comment: @dcsuka updated the date column header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tidyverse option using `hms` could look as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(hms)

df %>%
  mutate(across(1:2, ~ as_hms(.)),
         duration = if_else(end_time < start_time,
                            as_hms(86400) - start_time + end_time,
                            end_time - start_time))

#   start_time end_time       date   duration
# 1   16:34:23 19:24:45 2019-04-02 10222 secs
# 2   23:12:34 04:12:34 2019-07-03 18000 secs
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(start_time = c("16:34:23", "23:12:34"), end_time = c("19:24:45", 
"04:12:34"), date = c("2019-04-02", "2019-07-03")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```